# how to set returnValue false without preventDefault in keypress event

Tags: javascript, input, keypress, preventdefault

I want to prevent only returning value without preventdefault on keypress event in javascript

```
<input type="text" placeholder="tag">
```

This function will set returnValue=false but can I set returnValue false without preventDefault().

```
let input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: what is it you're trying to prevent? Or do? It's unclear

Comment: I want to do "e.returnValue" is false. after that I want to add "input.value += e.key" and when text overflow in input. text should move left, but it is flowing at right side.